# Custom scheme URL in macCatalyst app doesn't work

Tags: swift, cocoa, url-scheme, mac-catalyst

I have a macCatalyst app, and I want to launch/open it from another app (e.g. Safari) via custom-scheme-URL along with parameters, something like `myCustomScheme://command?paramA=valueA`. As this is quite an usual pattern in iOS app, I can't get it work in macCatalyst.

I keep receiving:

```
typeForContentsOfURL:error: must be overridden for your application to support non-'file:' URLs.
```

I have tried to eliminate above error by:

- override `-[NSDocumentController typeForContentsOfURL:error:]` in plug-in bundle, return some UTI string;
- specify custom extensions in `Info.plist` using `CFBundleTypeExtensions`;

Neither `-application(_:open:options:)` of `AppDelegate` nor `-scene(_:openURLContexts:)` of `SceneDelegate` get called, although I could print out the custom URL in overriden method implemented in plug-in bundle.

Note:

- custom scheme is already registered in `Target` -> `Info` -> `URL Types`;

Did I miss something? Did I do something wrong? Can anyone help?

Comment: My guess is that the minimum version of your iOS project is iOS 13 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

After double checked my code in cocoa plug-in bundle, I found that I changed `[NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate` to a custom class and implemented some methods, and this is the reason why I keep receiving error:

```
typeForContentsOfURL:error: must be overridden for your application to support non-'file:' URLs.
```

By commenting out those codes, `-scene(_:openURLContexts:)` get called as expected.